# Display json object into html page during nested $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

AJAX result:

[image]

When I'm going to display this data in HTML other information displaying correctl, but when trying to display `all_images` and `all_amenties` data by using `.each` in same loop its showing `[object] [object]`. Below is my code:

```
"<div id='Carousel"+ this.product_id +"' class='carousel slide' style='width: auto; margin: 0 auto'>"+
      "<div class='carousel-inner'>"+
        $.each(this.all_images, function(k,v) {
            "<div class='item'>"+
                " <img src='"+ v +"' alt=''>"+
            "</div>"
        }) +
      "</div> "+
      "<a class='left carousel-control' href='#Carousel"+ this.product_id +"' data-slide='prev'>‹</a>"+
      "<a class='right carousel-control' href='#Carousel"+ this.product_id +"' data-slide='next'>›</a>"+
    "</div>"+
"</div>"+
```

Comment: please provide more details (like the full javascript function) and more description.

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate an `$.each` call to a string. The result is an object - hence what you see in the output, `[Object object]`.

To fix this you can generate the strings separately and concatenate them:

```
var html = this.all_images.map(function(src) {
  return '<div class="item"><img src="' + src + '" alt=""></div>';
}).join('');

html = '<div id="Carousel' + this.product_id + '" class="carousel slide" style="width: auto; margin: 0 auto"><div class="carousel-inner">' + html + '</div><a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel' + this.product_id + '" data-slide="prev">‹</a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel' + this.product_id + '" data-slide="next">›</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `$.each` to `$.map`, add a `return` before `"<div class='item'>"+` and add `.join('')` after `$.map()`. `$.map` calls the function for each value in the array, stores the return value of each function in a new array, and returns it. So:

`$.map([1, 2, 3], function (v) { return v * 2 }).join('') === '246'`